# Trouble Understanding How to Set Bits

Tags: c, bit

For an assignment in my systems class, we are learning how bit manipulation works and I'm having trouble implementing it into this function:

```
void setting_bits(int value, int pos, int n) {
    int n_val = value;
    
    printf("\nsetting_bits(0x%X, %i, %i) -> ",value,pos,n);
    
    int mask = 1;
    mask = (mask << n)-pos-1;
    n_val = n_val & ~mask;
    printf("0x%X",n_val);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Here is an example input output:

`setting_bits(0xA1B2C3D4, 1, 4) -> 0xA1B2C3DE`

I just don't understand how to go about the logic. I think I understand the basics like how the bits can be modified and how masking works but I'm not sure how to put it all together. My class forums didn't prove useful nor does my professor respond to emails so I'm here for last resort. Anything response will be appreciated. I don't want to end up hating hexadecimal for the rest of my career.

Comment: Exactly what is this function supposed to do?

Comment: @Dmitri It is supposed to set each of the n consecutive bits of value at bit position pos, pos + 1, ..., pos + n - 1, to bit value 1, and prints out the result in hexadecimal.

Comment: `mask = (mask << n)-pos-1` doesn't seem to make sense, does it? You're subtracting the position (minus 1) from the mask itself and making that the new mask.

Comment: Maybe `value | ((1u << n) - 1) << pos` ?  `(1u << n) - 1` to get the right number of set bits, then shift into position, and OR with `value` to set them all.

Comment: @Dmitri Yes this works! But I want to be able to understand it I guess. What does the 1u come from? I get why its being subtracted by 1 (so it has the mask). Is the position being shifted for putting the mask into place? If you would like, you can write this as an answer and I'll mark it as solved below! Thank you regardless!

Comment: `1u` is just 1 as an unsigned int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a rewrite of the function:

```
void setting_bits(unsigned value, int pos, int n) {
    printf("\nsetting_bits(0x%X, %i, %i) -> ",value,pos,n);

    unsigned n_val = value | ((1u << n) - 1) << pos;
    
    printf("0x%X\n", n_val);
}
```

...to set `n` consecutive bits starting at bit position `pos` in `value` and display the result.

The key part here is `value | ((1u << n) - 1) << pos`.

`(1u << n)` gets us one bit set followed by `n` zero bits.  We then subtract 1 from that, which gives us `n` set bits instead.  Then we shift all that left by `pos` to get it into the correct position.  Finally, we bitwise OR it with the old value which gives us value, but with all those bits set if they weren't already.

An example using 8 bits in binary, with `value` of 0101 0101, `n` of 3, and `pos` of 2:

```
(1u << n)                       -->   00000001b << 3        --> 00001000b
((1u << n) - 1)                 -->   00001000b - 1         --> 00000111b
((1u << n) - 1) << pos          -->   00000111b << 2        --> 00011100b
value | ((1u << n) - 1) << pos  -->   01010101b | 00011100b --> 01011101b
```